# Не могу подключить шрифт Montserrat к проекту. В чем проблема?

Tags: html, css, шрифты

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p class="paragraph">Lorem Ipsum является текст-заполнитель обычно используется в графических, печать и издательской индустрии для предварительного просмотра макета и визуальных макетах.</p>
</body>
</html>

* {
  /*правильное отображение элементов с учетом всех марджинов и падингов. в начале очистим, чтобы задать потом*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@font-face{
    font-family: "Montserrat";
  src: url(fonts/Montserrat-Italic.ttf) format("truetype");
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  /*если нет сетки, то в фигме можно посмотреть выделяя от лого до конца элемента навигационного меню*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.paragraph{
    font-family: "Montserrat";
}
```